# Extend DropDownList to add ListSearchExtender

Tags: extend, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to extend DropDownList to add ListSearchExtender.

Using the code below, the control works well in runtime but in design time it give me this error:

> SearchDropDownList - DdlTest There was an error rendering the
>   control. Page cannot be null. Please ensure that this operation is
>   being performed in the context of an ASP.NET request.

I'd like to understand the cause of this error.

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:SearchDropDownList runat=\"server\"></{0}:SearchDropDownList>")]
public class SearchDropDownList : DropDownList
{
    private ListSearchExtender listSearchExt = new ListSearchExtender();
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        ReloadSettings();
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter w)
    {
        base.Render(w);
        listSearchExt.RenderControl(w);
    }

    public void ReloadSettings()
    {
        listSearchExt.TargetControlID = this.ID;
        listSearchExt.ID = this.ID + "_CalendarExtender";

        if (Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Control item in Controls)
            {
                if (item.ID == listSearchExt.ID)
                {
                    Controls.Remove(item);
                }
            }
        }
        Controls.Add(listSearchExt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it by simple way i am not sure if it will make problem in future but for now it work well

```
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter w)
    {
        base.Render(w);
        if (!this.DesignMode)
        {
            listSearchExt.RenderControl(w);
        }
    }
```